# SyntaxFactory.BinaryExpression throwing ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, roslyn

With the following code, I'm getting a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException from  Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll.

Am I doing something wrong? The Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll assembly version is 1.1.0.0.

```
var binaryExpression = SyntaxFactory.BinaryExpression(
      SyntaxKind.SimpleAssignmentExpression
    , SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("MyProperty")
    , SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("value") );
```

Comment: What message & stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a specific AssignmentExpression that you need to create. Roslyn doesn't model assignments as binary operators.

Comment: That was the push I needed.  Thanks.  I changed "SyntaxFactory.BinaryExpression" to "SyntaxFactory.AssignmentExpression" and that did the trick.  I was following another example about how to make field backed property and they were using "BinaryExpression".

Comment: Several years ago we did have assignments in binary expressions, maybe it is an outdated example?